# Hazelcast enable rest-api

Tags: api, rest, hazelcast

I have hazelcast version 3.8.3. I want to enable rest api.

I wrote in the config:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rest-api` section was added in 3.12, you're using 3.8.

An upgrade should sort it.

The latest Hazelcast 3 series is 3.12.9, but it's still old.

Current Hazelcast is Hazelcast 5. If you can upgrade, going to 5.1.1 would be better, the very latest (as of time of writing) -- even faster, more features, etc.

Comment: I updated the hazelcast to version 3.12.4. Will my config work now? Do I understand correctly that I can check the operation of the rest api with the command "curl --data "test&\12345" http://test:5555/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/state" ?

Comment: The latest 3.12.* is 3.12.12 not 3.12.9, my mistake. But all of the 3.12.* should behave the same. If REST is enabled, [this](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/manual/html-single/index.html#using-the-rest-endpoint-groups) should show the way. Or just try `curl http://127.0.0.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster`

Comment: thank you very much. when is the user interface available? since version 4.2?